# How to capture video using intent in Galaxy Tab?

Tags: android, android-intent, galaxy-tab

I have an intent that calls the video capture activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,  Uri.fromFile(videoFile));
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
            startActivityForResult(intent,CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

It works fine on my SE X8, but on Galaxy Tab the video capture activity never quits. After I stop recording, there is no button to quit the video capture. Is there any extra parameter I need to set?

Comment: Have you try this : [videobasics](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just remove this line:

`intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,  Uri.fromFile(videoFile));`

After that everything worked as expected for me on Galaxy Tab.

Answer (score 1):

Removing

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(videoFile));
```

works, but then you will have to capture the uri with

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if ((requestCode == VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {

        // The URI string is in intent.getData());
    }
}
```

and move the video to another location if is the functionality you need.

The crazy thing is that MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT works perfectly with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare your own `SurfaceHolder` class for this. Just try this [link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/04/simple-exercise-of-video-capture-using.html) It's wokring perfectly.